# Wordpress Plugin: Thethe Image slider - image links

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions, slider

I have moved my wordpress site onto a new domain - 
everything else is working fine, except for my sliders made with "The The image slider".  It imported the sliders, along with their slides.  however - the image paths of the images still point to the "old" site, and therefore the image slides are not showing?

I have tried to adjust the permissions of the cache folder in CPanel, and all the permissions seem in order.  I have also done a "search and replace" with a plugin and according to the plugin result, all the paths are changed?  I can open the slides images by using the new path which shows that the images are in the new upload folder, however the path to the images is still the "old" path in the plugin's slider settings

Is there someway I could perhaps change the image paths to the new domain?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thethe-image-slider/

Comment: How do they appear in the database? Might be the problem is right there.

Comment: that is part of the problem. I am not sure how to locate that particular database. I did  edit a few other plugins through PhpMyAdmin, but not sure how to find this one's database?

Comment: If the plugin doesn't create it's own tables - not a separate database - then you might find it under the wp_options table.